# "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when accessing Photobucket API

Tags: c#, .net, api, networking, photobucket

When using the Photobucket API, it says...

> [SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host]    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +139
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) +146

Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: So... what endpoint do you use? What code does issue that request? What does a tool like Fiddler or Postman say about the same request? What does your browser say about going to http://api.photobucket.com? Please read [ask] and include all relevant information in your question. But it does seem like their API is down.

Comment: Why do you think their API is down?

Comment: Because the server closes the connection. It could also occur after it receives a request with an incorrect or missing API key, but I know as much as is in your question.

Comment: ok, I'm going with the former for now, as this code has worked fine for many years. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked by Photobucket and they said: photobucket api is disabled for external using.

Comment: Did they say why?

Comment: I think, because of changing they businesses model.  But they did no say why ;(

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to Photobucket and got this response:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to us. Unfortunately, at this time we are not allowing outside parties to access the Photobucket API.
>
> I apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you. Please let us know if you have any additional questions
>
> Thank you.

So sounds like it's a policy change.